# C++ clr заполнить Dictionary в нативной части кода

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr, консоль

Есть желание заполнять Dictionary вида `Dictionary<Enum,Struct>` в нативной части кода, используя возможности трансляции через `vcclr.h`. Толком ничего не получается, студия ругается почти на каждую строчку. Есть ли доступный пример использования? буду признателен.

Я так понимаю что надо создавать дополнительные мелкие классы по конвертации, или я  не так понял описание как это работает..

Comment: "Диктонарий" - это пять! :)

Comment: @Harry, Это гугло-клава :) рад что доставил минуты радости :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результатом поиска решений в этой области привели к нескольким направлениям:

1. Использовать `#include <cliext/adapter>`, это [ms решение](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-convert-from-a-stl-clr-container-to-a-dotnet-collection?view=vs-2017) по сути работает только внутри `C++` функции (unmanaged). Экспортировать в `C++clr` (managed) код, то есть вернуть результатом работы функции не удастся, для этих целей не подходит.
2. Интересное, хоть и не очень свежее решение [marshalfx](https://github.com/goldshtn/marshalfx), но требует добавления описания собственных не generic объектов. С generic'ами работает отлично.
3. Использование нативных прокси классов и директивы `gcroot` (vcclr.h). Именно на нем я остановился, по порядку:

Например все это проживает в нэймспейс:

```
  namespace MyNameSpace
  {
```

Имеем managed класс:

```
public ref class MyData
{
public:
   properties MyNameSpace::MyEnum MEnum;
   properties Int32 MyInt;
   properties Sting ^ MyStr;
}
```

Пишем для него прокси класс для unmanaged C++ кода:

```
class ProxyMyData
{
public:
    ProxyMyData()
    {
        vHandle = gcnew MyNameSpace::MyData();
    }

    gcroot<MyNameSpace::MyData^> vHandle;

    void Set(MyNameSpace::MyEnum id, Int32 idx, wchar_t *wstr)
    {
        vHandle->MEnum = id;
        vHandle->MyInt = idx;
        vHandle->MyStr = gcnew String(wstr);
    }
}
```

Определяем сокращение для Dictionary, чтобы было меньше букв :)

```
  namespace SCG = System::Collections::Generic;
```

Пишем прокси класс для Dictionary (unmanaged C++ код):

```
class ProxyDictionary
{
public:
    ProxyDictionary()
    {
        vHandle = gcnew SCG::Dictionary<MyNameSpace::MyEnum, MyNameSpace::MyData^>();
    }

    gcroot<SCG::Dictionary<MyNameSpace::MyEnum, MyNameSpace::MyData^>^> vHandle;

    void Add(MyNameSpace::MyEnum id, gcroot<MyNameSpace::MyData^> val)
    {
        vHandle->Add(id, val);
    }
};
```

Как это использовать в `C++` unmanaged коде:

```
SCG::Dictionary<MyNameSpace::MyEnum, MyNameSpace::MyData^> ^ MyClass::MyFunc(Int32 idx, wchar_t *wstr)
{
    auto pdict = std::make_unique<ProxyDictionary>();
    auto pdata = std::make_unique<ProxyMyData>();
    pdata.get()->Set(
         MyNameSpace::MyEnum::TAG_1,
         idx,
         wstr
    );
    pdict.get()->Add(
         MyNameSpace::MyEnum::TAG_0,
         pdata.get()->vHandle
    );
    return pdict.get()->vHandle;
}
```

Для удобства создания прокси классов так-же можно написать простенький темплейт:

```
    template<class T>
    class ProxyObject
    {
    public:
        gcroot<T^> vHandle;
        ProxyObject() : vHandle(gcnew T()) {}
    };

    class ProxyMyData : public ProxyObject<MyNameSpace::MyData>
    {
    public:
       Set(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    }
```

Надеюсь что сэкономил кому либо пару лишних часов, информации на эту тему не очень много, к сожалению.